# Support for Different Authentication for different tenant using Identity Server

Tags: authentication, multi-tenant, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core 2. I'm using Saaskit Multitenant for multi tenancy. 
With the recent changes in Core2, Configure():UseXYZAuthentication has been replaced by ConfigureService():AddXYZ.

ConfigureService runs only once and not per tenant. Thus all tenant need to support the same authentication. like Cookie and Google for example. (We can configure separate authentication per tenant by Implementing a class using IConfigureNamedOptions interface.

But How can i do it so that One tenant Use Google authentication and another tenant use Microsoft Authentication ? I need to register the Authentication middleware per tenant. 
In ASP.net Core 1, it was possible as we were registering the authentication inside UsePerTenant method. which is not the case with Asp.net Core 2.

Looking forward for some help!

Comment: About to tackle this myself. I think you'd need different DI configuration per tenant. Aspnetcore doesn't support that out-of-the-box, hence the reason for the StructureMap project in the SaasKit repo to support child containers.

Comment: Himal Patel, Did you got the answer for this query? I need the same

Answer (score 0):

You're in full control of the sign in flow for the end user so you can invoke any scheme you like once you know which tenant they are. How do you resolve the tenant currently?

The (very simplified) psuedo MVC code might look something like:

```
var tenantConfig = resolveTenantConfig(Request); 
return Challenge(tenantConfig.Scheme);
```

Long story short, you don't *have* to wire up the middleware to be automatic and can write your own decision making logic within the MVC framework if you wish.

Comment: I'm using Tenant Resolver to resolve the tenant using host name. What i thought to implement is to inject all the authentication that I would like my application to support in middleware. and then Implement IOptionsMonitor for each of them. And then on the Login view, based on the tenant show only the auth provider supported by that tenant. I'll store the supported auth provider and configuration for each tenant.

Comment: Will tenants have config specific to them (i.e. using their own external IDP) or will they just have the option to use different social sign ins that are statically configured? Another thing to consider it callback URLs - you probably don't want to have to configure a different one for each tenant (different host name) but if you do then you'll need to ensure that's configured correctly.